# How to use Array and file handling in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file-handling

How to use array and file handling in C? I am new in programming. I want to know more about C.

Answer (score 1):

I am brıefly answering yout question and explaining the array or file use.
Firstly use this library: `#include <file.h>` top of the codes.

Or this is the code for opening a file

```
if(fopen(“test.txt”,”r”)){

printf(“file was opened”);

}else{

printf(“Failed”);

}
```

Reading and writing from files can greatly facilitate the calculation function. The functions fscanf and fprintf are derivatives of the scanf and printf functions, which are learned when the C language is first learned. Some samples were given:

```
Int i;

Fscanf (fp, "% d", & i);

Fprintf (fp, "% d", i);
```

It's a number identifier. This variable is read from the file in the second line with a function fscanf. This function uses an additional file pointer parameter, unlike the scanf function, which is apparent at first glance. This parameter is the first parameter. The "fp" file pointer in the above example is an example of such a file pointer.

### There is no difference between standard prinft function

These are the basic funcs in file operations in C.

> Fopen () Opens a file.
>
> Fclose () Closes a file.
>
> Fputc () and putc () write a character to the file.
>
> Fgetc () and getc () read a character from the file.
>
> Fseek () Finds a specific byte in a file.
>
> Fprintf () writes the structured data to the file.
>
> Fscanf () Reads structured data from file.
>
> Feof () Returns the correct value when the end of file is reached.
>
> Ferror () Gives an accurate value in case of an error.
>
> Rewind () Starts the active location of the file.
>
> Remove () Removes the file.
>
> Fflush () Clears the buffer memory.

---

MODS

> r     read only
>
> w     write only
>
> a     append
>
> r+    read and write. But the file has to be firstly.
>
> w+    read and write. There is no problem if the file exists or not. It
>   will be created anyway.
>
> a+   Read and write. It opens to add data to the end of a saved file.

I hope it will be helpful for your beginning, improve your logic by writing so much.

Comment: I know how to use file handling but my logics are not clear I am BS IT student first sir tell us about these and second day quiz and I got 0 marks because I know how to open a file and how close it but I can't apply my mind about this because my logics are not clear

Comment: give me a sample program and let me know how it work... it

Comment: Mert, please take a moment to understand how to apply formatting to questions here, in particular the code block (there's a button for it) and the inline quote device (use backticks, `like so`). Questions and answers here nearly always benefit from an appropriate use of formatting.